# How to load a service in React before rendering components?

Tags: reactjs

If I have a service that calls some REST API resources, but in order to get the URL of that API need to perform another REST call locally from the same deployed site and read that URL from a config file.

I made that call inside the constructor of the service, and set a local variable with the response of that call.

The problem starts when other components try to call that service functions, the URL is still undefined at that point and the call fails.

For example:

Service

```
    let webServicesBaseUrl;

class ApiService extends EventEmitter {

    // webServicesBaseUrl;

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.getWebServicesBaseUrl().then( (response) => {
            webServicesBaseUrl = response;
            console.log("..........................", webServicesBaseUrl)
        })
    }

 isAuthenticated(/*userName*/) {
        const url = new URL(webServicesBaseUrl + '/SessionManager/isAuthenticated');
        //     params = {user: userName}
        // Object.keys(params).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]))

        return fetch(url,
            {
                method: 'GET',
                credentials: 'include',
                // mode: "cors",
                headers: headers
            }
        ).then((response) => response.text())
            .then((data) => {
                return data;
            })
            .catch(console.log);
    }}

export const service = new ApiService();
```

Component

```
import {service} from "../stores/RestService";
componentWillMount() {

    service.isAuthenticated(/*this.props.user*/).then((response) => {
        if (response !== 'true') {
            this.props.history.push('/login')
        }
    });
```

Getting:

[image]

Comment: I updated my answer. and It will work well now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue1:**

It seems like `isAuthenticated` is async function.

And it will be better to call this in `componentDidMount`.

An API call with fetch or `axios` inside `componentWillMount` will not return before the first render. This means the component will render with empty data at least once.

And `componentWillMount` is deprecated and not recommended.

Please try this in `componentDidMount`.

**Issue2:**
Do not fetch in constructor.

It will be better to do get `webServicesBaseUrl` in `isAuthenticated` function.

```
 authenticateByService(baseUrl) {
    // Haha! here it is. You can now use baseUrl here and verify the user!
 }

 isAuthenticated() {
   if (this.webServicesBaseUrl) {
      authenticateByService(this.webServicesBaseUrl);
      return;
   }
   this.getWebServicesBaseUrl().then( (response) => {
     this.webServicesBaseUrl = response;
     authenticateByService(this.webServicesBaseUrl);
   })
 }
```

**EDIT:**

```
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.getWebServicesBaseUrl().then( (response) => {
            webServicesBaseUrl = response; // THIS IS THE REASON!!!
        })
    }

    isAuthenticated(/*userName*/) {
        // webServiesBaseUrl is undefined
        const url = new URL(webServicesBaseUrl + '/SessionManager/isAuthenticat')
    ...
```

Instead of normal `webServiesBaseUrl`, you have to use `this.webServicesBaseUrl`.

```
this.webServicesBaseUrl = response;
...
const url = new URL(this.webServicesBaseUrl + '/SessionManager/isAuthenticat')
```

Comment: Thanks Antonio. Moving to componentDidMount didn't help, and I have many other methods rather than isAuthenticated that is using the same webServicesBaseUrl, so calling the getWebServicesUrl from all will be an overhead

Comment: @zbeedatm Ah, I see. I updated my answer. Pay attention to edited section.

Comment: I had this.webServicesBaseUrl  before but it didn't make a different :). anyway the problem is only with the HomePage component at the beginning when loading... so calling the getWebServicesUrl there only once and perform the isAuthenticated in then clause solved the problem... later on all other calls will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an initial state, for example, isUrlReady: false, then set it to true when you receive the information. Then do this:

```
    if(this.state.isUrlReady){
set your const here
return some data after the config
} else {
return (<p>loading</p>); // example
}
```

you can also use the React hooks to do this. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html